# How to enable F5 URL at Open Shift container level

Tags: openshift, load-balancing, livenessprobe

currently we have a spring boot application on on-prem data centers. We enabled F5 URL (https://prd.myapp.com/) for the external systems interaction.

For example:
initially, external systems used to hit our application API with host name.

http://prd-trd01/conextapi/retrieve/customer/data
later we had upgraded to below (F5 URL)
https://prd.myapp.com/conextapi/retrieve/customer/data

at F5 Server (network server) we have enabled layer 7 & load balancer at F5 server, which checks the health of our application and route the traffic in round rabin fashion to multiple servers (physical)

our current F5 URL is: https://prd.myapp.com for the external system to interface.

Now, we are planning to containerize our applications on OpenShift (on-prem) with two clusters.

Question is, is there any way to enable F5 URL (like above) to check multiple pod status route the traffic to multiple clusters based on availability?

Please guide & navigate me to the right direction to achieve this.

We tried to enable liveness Readiness prob but pod is not came up errored out with with connection refused.

Comment: "We tried to enable liveness Readiness prob but pod is not came up errored out with with connection refused." That sounds like you've misconfigured your probes. Maybe you want to open a new question to resolve that issue first? It's not clear how it relates to the question about enabling the F5 load balancer.